# is String created by literal primitive or referenced type?

Tags: java, string

i'm already tired but i'm wondering if (see the topic).

```
String a = "first";
    String b = "second";
    a = b;
    b = "third";
    System.out.println(a + ", " + b);
```

-my question is why i got the output: "second, third". Isn't is String referenced type? So after command "a = b;" why didnt change both of variables? Wasn't both variables referencing to the same object? (or the same String from the String pool?)

Comment: If you did `Foo a = new Foo(3); Foo b = new Foo(4); a = b; b = new Foo(5);`, would you expect `a` to be altered by the final line?

Comment: [Is Java pass-by-reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: First fact that you should consider is `String is an immutable type`.

Comment: @mostruash No, that has absolutely nothing to do with it. This is all about references.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It absolutely has something to do with it. If `String` is immutable, than the assignment operator must initialize a new instance of the String class because there is NO other option if String is immutable (you get the point, I won't go into detailed analysis of how JRE handles strings).

Comment: @mostruash I think you're confusing things. Immutability is unrelated to the assignment operator. If `String` was mutable, this question and its answer would be the same: changing the value (the reference) that one variable holds does not change the value of any other variable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If String was mutable, the answer would be the same. But if you assume that String is immutable, you can conclude that it's impossible to expect both `a` and `b` (after `a = b`) to refer to the same string of characters after executing `b = "third"`. The reasoning behind it is in my previous comment. What I meant is you can find the answer to this question without going into reference types.

Comment: @mostruash They're just two unrelated things. The assignment operator works the same for immutable types as it does for mutable types. Exchange `String` with any other type, the result is the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51037/discussion-between-mostruash-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't is String referenced type?

Yes, String is a reference type.

> So after command "a = b;" why didnt change both of variables?

Because you only said to change the value of one variable at a time.

This statement:

```
b = "third";
```

*only* changes the value of `b`. It changes it to refer to a different string. The value of `a` remains as it was before - a reference to a string with contents "second".

It's very important to distinguish between these concepts:

- Variables
- Values
- References
- Objects

When you write:

```
a = b;
```

That just means "take the current value of `b`, and make it the new value of `a`." It *doesn't* say "make `a` and `b` equivalent variables, so that any change to the value of either variable affects the other variable". When you change the value of `b` in the next line to refer to a different object, that does *nothing* to either `a` or the object that the value of `a` refers to.

Now I suspect you were being confused because of code like this:

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder b = a;
a.append("foo");
System.out.println(b); // Prints foo
```

In this case the `a.append()` call doesn't change the *value* of `a` or `b` at all... both variables still have values which refer to the same `StringBuilder` object. The `append` method instead changes the data within that object... so when you print the contents of the object in the final line, getting at it via `b`, you still see `foo` because you're still referring to the same (modified) object.

Comment: yes of course i didnt mean a= b; but b = "third"; I'm very tired of this for now i must take a break, thanks.

Comment: @CharlieHarper: The rest of my answer still applies. Changing the value of `a` doesn't change the value of `b`, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> So after command "a = b;" why didnt change both of variables?

*Variables* for reference types "refer to" *objects*. That is, reference variables hold a *reference value*. (A reference value can be thought of as an opaque number or handle, such that it uniquely identifies an object.)

However, variables are *not* references (in an "alias/C++" sense) themselves and each variable holds an independent, but possibly duplicate, *value*. Thus the assignment only affects - as in, assigns a new [reference] value - to the *particular* variable while it leaves the values stored in all other variables alone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `a` and `b` are both referencing the same string in the pool after `a=b`:

```
         String pool
             "first"                

[a] -------> "second"
                ^
[b] ------------|             "third"
```

However, the re-assignment of `b` does not affect the reference stored in `a`, as they are two distinct local variables that can reference different (immutable as always) strings. You will see:

```
         String pool
             "first"                

[a] -------> "second"

[b] ------->  "third"
```